# CakePHP htmlhelper link method is omitting the id paramter of the request URL

Tags: cakephp, html-helper

My view contains a link that I use to change page language. The index, add pages are all fine. But when it comes to "edit" or "view" page for single article where there is an ID number at the end of the URL, that number got omitted somehow on this link. The link becomes

```
http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php/categories/view/lang:chi
```

Obviously the id number is missing. The link should be like this

```
http://www.xxxxxx.com/index.php/categories/view/5/lang:chi
```

The code to generate the link in the view file is this

```
$this->Html->link($language, array('lang' => $code));
```

I don't know why only the URL with an ID number at the end is having such problem. I used bake so the controller view action is like this:

```
    public function view($id = null) {
            $this->Category->id = $id;
            if (!$this->Category->exists()) {
                    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid category'));
            }
            $this->set('category', $this->Category->read(null, $id));
    }
```

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the id in the link array, it won't be used. The only "magic" ones added if you omit them are the controller and action.

You will need to pass the id when creating the link:

```
$this->Html->link($language, array('lang' => $code, $id));
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Though I have to check the exist of the ID which I used $this->request-pass[0] then use that as the $id if existed. Any other easier way?

Comment: You could set it in the controller, since it's passed anyway, like `$this->set('id', $id);`